# On a tag page, why does score (not rep) drop 70 points overnight instead of going up by 15?

Tags: support, bug

**Edit: Summary of Question and Answer for Speed-Readers:** @animuson cracked the mystery, but the gritty details are in the comments so I'll bring them up to the surface. You know the 30-day rolling `score` you see on the users page of any tag, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers)?  I had assumed that the score was from taking all `upvotes - downvotes` that took place in the last 30 days on any answer we posted anytime. It turns out that we are taking all `upvotes - downvotes` that took place in the last 30 days on any answer we posted in the last 30 days! Nothing wrong with that, just a nice mystery to solve. Thanks to both @animuson and @icktoofay.

**The Question**

To clarify, this is not a question about a drop in reputation, but about an unusual drop in the score on a tag page—I have read questions such as [sudden rep drop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc) and seen the [rep recap page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and have no issues with my rep.

I am confused!... On a tag's 30-day score page, my score dropped from 325 yesterday to 254 today, when I expected it to go up by about 15 (added a 200 day, removed a 40 day). Those 80 missing score points are a discrepancy that would correspond to about 800 reputation points, though, thankfully, it's only reflected in that tag's 30-day score, as the rep itself hasn't done anything weird.

Since my rep hasn't dropped, that doesn't seem to add up... unless overnight, the tag was removed from a lot of the questions I answered... But that doesn't seem to be the case.

It's not the end of the world, points come and go... And 30 days from now, it will be a whole new score, so in the grand scheme of things.... But I am curious to understand how it all works.

Would appreciate any insights! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean the number under the **"Last 30 Days"** column? That 90-score answer of yours is no longer within the last 30 days. You posted it on May 11. It's now June 12.

Comment: Aha... I sense an Aha! coming there, thank you... :) Yes, the "last-30 days" column... So do  you mean that the `score` is computed from your answers in the last 30 days? As opposed to computing it from all upvotes your received in the last 30 days (regardless of the answer's date)? Because that would suggest that if you receive an upvote today on an answer of yours from two years ago, it does not participate in your rolling 30-day score. And that's probably what's happening... Is that how you understand it? Thanks!

Comment: *That* score is computed for the last 30 days. You can find your all-time score in [your tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1078583/zx81?tab=tags).

Comment: Yes, I know it's computed for the last 30 days... See the column of numbers in my question. :) That's not what my reply to your post is about... It's about the computation method. Are we taking all `upvotes - downvotes` that took place in the last 30 days on any answer we posted anytime? Or, as your answer hints, are we taking all `upvotes - downvotes` that took place in the last 30 days on any answer we posted in the last 30 days? I assumed the first, but it must be the second... Is that your understanding too?

Comment: It's on posts that were created within the last 30 days.

Comment: Right-o then, that answers it perfectly. It was a big mystery to me and you cracked it. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect one of your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1078583) or [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1078583) was deleted. Supposing it has existed for long enough, [its deletion will not affect your reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/if-i-delete-an-answer-do-i-lose-reputation), but it will affect your cumulative score in a tag.

Comment: Aha... or maybe many questions have been deleted! (I don't have one high-scoring question that was deleted.) That could make sense... So maybe the elves have been busy cleaning up the questions. Good on them. Thank you for explaining! :) Btw, do you happen to know if there is a place where I can see which of the questions on which I had answers were deleted?

Comment: @zx81: Click the ‘answers’ link in my answer, which should bring you to a list of your answers that have recently been deleted. Clicking on any should bring you to the answer, and scrolling up you should be able to see the question. (Though, you might not be able to see the question if you don't have 10K reputation—but if you have an answer, maybe you will be able to. I'm not sure. Try it.)